# Handle possible not existing function in a version of com

Tags: c++, dll, error-handling, com

I have a question for com handling.

I'm using a third party dll which I include through #import, using named_guids as argument. I don't know if I should use another argument or not for proper importing..?

The problem is that there are different versions of the dll. One particular function that I'm using is added in the last version of the dll. So, if a costumer have an older version there is an exception - access violation executing location (some address). I understand that the error is telling me that the function can't be found, but how to catch this exception?

I tried with **try-catch(_com_error)** - nothing, **try-catch(std::exception)** - nothing, even **try-catch(...)** - still nothing.

Can I catch this kind of exception and log the exception and tell the costumer that there is a problem with the dll?

I'm not working with LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer of the third party DLL violated a core principle of COM: Interfaces are immutable. This implies that once published, an interface may not change whatsoever. You are seeing the effect of what happens when this rule isn't followed: your call to the non-existent method results in an access violation.

If the COM interface derives from `IDispatch`, then you have an easy way to check, whether a method exists or not: Use [`GetIDsOfNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221306(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the `DISPID` of the method. If it doesn't exist, the function will return with a `DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME` error:

```
DISPID dispID;
BSTR methodName = SysAllocString(L"MyMethod");
// Check hr return value
HRESULT hr = piDisp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &methodName, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispID);
SysFreeString(methodName);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This is what I needed.

Comment: @Alex, then you should give the third party developers a major chewing for breaking this rule. This is almost literally the first thing you learn about creating interfaces in COM. There is no excuse.